# How can I get the google search snippets using Python?

Tags: python

I am now trying the python module google which only return the url from the search result. And I want to have the snippets as information as well, how could I do that?(Since the google web search API is deprecated)

Comment: use `BeautifulSoup` or `Selenium`

Comment: [Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to extract your own snippets by opening and reading the url in the search result.